# ERROR: Target table [X] does not allow UPDATE Row # [0] in bad file

Tags: sql-server, informatica

We are getting this error on Informatica when executing a simple UPDATE command while connecting to SQL Server 2016 SP2.  We've tested the service account from SQL Server Management Studio manually and it works fine.

Here is the version of SQL Server we have installed.

Informatica error:

[image]

Informatica drivers:

[image]

Comment: The answers posted here did not help.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16365488/informatica-writes-rejected-rows-into-a-bad-file-how-to-avoid-that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the error message it looks like you do not have the "Update" enabled for the target under the mapping tab in Session properties. Please select the "Update as Update" for the target as in the below snapshot.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you are using update strategy you can point to data driven option in session level properties. Make sure you have a primary key available in the target. If you are rejecting any records, use a filter/router to reject the data.

Thank you

Comment: Just to elaborate The error is saying that the table doesn't allow UPDATE. The Row # [0] in bad file is explaining that Informatica has sent this record to the badfile configured in your session properties.